# Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout does not work as a parent in style.xml in android

Tags: android, styles, android-tablayout

I searched google but can not find solution.I need to define different styles for `Tablayout` for themes.I figure it out how to include my `Toolbar` style but can not make it work because of `Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout`.When I define it as a name it works but I can only use it for one style.When I define it as parent and include it to my theme with `android:tabWidgetStyle` it does not work

**As a parent**(which does not work)

```
<style name="tabayout" parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/deep_orange_300_colorAccent</item>
        <item name="tabBackground">@color/deep_orange_300_colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

**Second**(which works but I can only use it once, but I need to define 14 style)

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/red_200_colorAccent</item>
        <item name="tabBackground">@color/red_200_colorAccent</item>
        <item name="tabTextColor">@color/red_200_colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
```

**Edit**

I want to style `TabLayout` for specific custom theme.I want to make `Toolbar` `background` `textColor` etc for chosen colour by user. So I used `Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout` as a name to style TabLayout and include it with `android:tabWidgetStyle` it worked.But when I use it as `parent` it does not work.Here My Theme

This works.But when I define `Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout` as a parent it does not work.

```
<style name="AppTheme_red_200" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red_200_colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/red_200_colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/red_200_colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red_400_colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="">
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/red_200_colorAccent</item>
        <item name="tabBackground">@color/red_200_colorAccent</item>
        <item name="tabTextColor">@color/red_200_colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I use it as parent and include it but does not work

Comment: I edited my question.Sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: Can you give workaround how to style my TabLayouts?